# Ethereum vs NXT Comparison Chart?

Tags: nxt, ethereum

Where can I find a comparison chart between these crypto 2.0 currencies like NXT and ethereum? What are some of the major advantages of each of these coins in relation to one another?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be in Ethereum Forum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have composed one of the more comprehensive comparison charts of the various Crypto 2.0 platforms over at http://tiny.cc/Crypto (or [a more direct link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FdxxnujeMb_1kWlz1Esqut_jmmWNicbS3Meh1F83tUo/edit#gid=0)).

It currently has pretty comprehensive comparison between Ripple, Ethereum, Mastercoin, NXT, Counterparty and BitShares, with information on other platforms also available although in smaller quantity.

Comment: nice write up. would be great if it was a wiki of some sort so we can suggest changes. possibly color code the columns and text wrap the cells?

Comment: @duckx A wiki would be nice, but it would have to be monitored to prevent vandalism and putting wrong information in. Bitcoin wiki does not like any alt content, and beyond that there is no authoritative source for altcoin information, so I just keep it in a google spreadsheet for now. If anyone has info to update, they can contact me and I will put the data in.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a really good source on the difference between etherium and NXT [1] and here's more between mastercoin and etherium [2]

Hope this helps!

[1] http://prisonorfreedom.com/what-is-the-difference-between-ethereum-vs-bitcoin-vs-nxt/

[2] http://prisonorfreedom.com/what-is-the-difference-between-ethereum-vs-nxt-or-any-other-alt-coin/

Comment: Is it just me or is it annoying to read through transcripts?

Answer (score 1):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0RNywMP.jpg]

here you go :) it is not finished yet......

Comment: link to the image?

Comment: [You can click here to view the image.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nf959.jpg) Alternatively, e.g. in Firefox you can right-click the image above and select "View Image" from the context menu.

Comment: i think there is an updated one with ethereum?

Comment: @duckx, Right-click >> "search Google for image".

Comment: No newer one, would be great to get one!

Answer (score 1):

There is now this site comparing bitcoin 2.0 techno (all the ones using the bitcoin blockchain): bitcoin2comparator.org.

[image: Bitcoin 2.0 Protocols]

Comment: of all 2.0 coins ... they seem to have left the elephant out of that chart, nxt. i wonder y.

Comment: Just a note. These are NOT Bitcoin 2.0. They work on top of the blockchain, but that doesn't make them Bitcoin themselves. Bitcoin is still at version 0.9.3 at the time of writing.

Comment: Does this site still exist? I'm getting an error.

Comment: Domain expired already